# Why one of two HDDs wakes from sleep during the first Linux graphical login?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, login, hdparm, udisks

I have two archive HDDs, which I use very infrequently (I mount their partitions manually less than once a week on average). Since I turn my computer off at night, I tried to prevent them from spinning up on everyday's boot, but *that* seems way too difficult: [requires patching the Linux kernel](https://superuser.com/a/1210097/903340). As a worse but simpler alternative, I created a simple systemd unit that puts the HDDs to sleep immediately after boot (`ExecStart=/usr/bin/hdparm -Y /dev/disk/by-id/...` and `WantedBy=multi-user.target`). This almost works: both disks spin down upon boot. I verified this by a terminal login in tty2: `sudo hdparm -C /dev/sd[bc]` reports `drive state is:  standby`.

However once I log in a graphical shell, one of the disks spins up audibly and *hdparm* reports `drive state is:  active/idle` for it. This happens both with XFCE and KDE Plasma 5 (Manjaro GNU/Linux with latest updates), and also with another user of the same system. After the disk awakens, I put it to sleep manually (`hdparm -Y ...`), and it never wakes again until I reboot the computer. Logging out, then in, even as another user, doesn't wake any of the disks again.

This awakening disk is always the same. I tried to swap SATA cables of these two HDDs, which exchanged their IDs (sdb<->sdc), but still the same physical HDD is awakened upon the first graphical login. This awakening disk is definitely not mentioned anywhere in my configuration files by its permanent ID because I purchased it recently (second-hand). More specifically, the disk that keeps sleeping is *Samsung HD103UJ* and the disk that awakens upon the first graphical login is *Samsung HD154UI*.

I am monitoring */dev/sd[bc]* accesses with *auditd*. The logs are practically the same for both disks. First I log in the tty2 console and run `sudo hdparm -C /dev/sd[bc]`: both disks are sleeping; then I switch to tty7 and log into XFCE from the lightdm screen; I quickly switch to tty2 and now one of the disks is no longer sleeping. The essence of the `sudo ausearch -f /dev/sdb` command output corresponding to these events:

```
comm="hdparm" exe="/usr/bin/hdparm"
comm="udisksd" exe="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd"
comm="hdparm" exe="/usr/bin/hdparm"
comm="udisksd" exe="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd"
comm="pool" exe="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd"
comm="pool" exe="/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd"
...
```

And so on. The `comm="pool"` line appears every 10 minutes in the log, or more often while *gnome-disks* is running, but the `comm="udisksd"` line doesn't appear until reboot. Assuming that *auditd* reports all disk accesses, this `comm="udisksd"` must be responsible for the waking up. But why only one of the 2 HDDs? Perhaps the offending HDD can be configured with `hdparm` not to awaken?

I compared `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` and `hdparm -I /dev/sdc` outputs with meld. Also tried `-Iv`, `-i` and `-iv` options instead of `-I`. The differences are pretty much limited to unique identifiers, disk sizes, geometry. The only difference that could cause this wake-up inconsistency is the Firmware Revision: *1A**A**01118* on the non-waking disk and *1A**G**01118* on the waking one.

Comment: I would have also guessed `udisks` from your initial description, because that's what causes my spun-down HDs to spin up. As I am not using a Gnome/KDE desktop, my solution was to disable udisks. I don't know why it only tries to spin up one disk on your system - what udisks does is to try to get info about the disks so it can present them via DBus to desktop apps.

Comment: Yes, `udisks` is probably at fault here. I wrote another systemd unit that puts the offending disk to sleep after the udisks2 service is started (`After=udisks2.service`, `WantedBy=udisks2.service`). This workaround prevents waking.

Comment: However, the workaround turned out to be incomplete, because this same offending HDD wakes up whenever I mount or unmount a partition using XFCE/GNOME GUI, or `udisksctl`. The other HDD stays asleep. Similarly to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457729/ubuntu-18-04-mount-umount-causes-drives-resume-from-standby-state, regular `mount`, `unmount` commands and also `systemd-mount`, `systemd-umount` don't wake any HDDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*udisksd* calls `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sd??` command for each ext2, ext3 and ext4 partition when the service is started and when it mounts/unmounts any disk. My awakening HDD contains an ext4 partition and so is waked by *udisksd*
=>`dumpe2fs`. The other HDD does not have any ext* partitions and so is never waked by *udisksd*.

Much more details can be found in comments to this *udisks* bug: https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/611. The bug is fixed in *udisks 2.8.4*, so it no longer wakes any HDDs when an unrelated partition is mounted or unmounted. The same HDD is still waked when *udisksd* starts, so I have to keep [the second systemd unit](https://superuser.com/questions/1371955/why-one-of-two-hdds-wakes-from-sleep-during-the-first-linux-graphical-login#comment2097624_1371955) that puts this HDD to sleep after the *udisks2* service is started.